# Bluej wont start. Nothing happens

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to run bluej. I downloaded BlueJ-linux-400.deb from bluej.org and installed it. When I click on the bluej icon, nothing happens.

help please.

edit:It turns out JDK wasn't installed properly, despite what it says on the bluej site - that it will be installed automatically.

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the details of how you installed it.

Comment: Add the link to the download site too...

Comment: It says on the bluej.org website *Ubuntu/Debian Requires OpenJDK or Oracle JDK (8u60 minimum, 8u121 best).* This package is called openjdk-8-jdk in the official Ubuntu repositories and its code is *8u121-b13-0ubuntu1*. Did you install openjdk-8-jdk too?

Answer (score 0):

It says on the bluej.org website *Ubuntu/Debian Requires OpenJDK or Oracle JDK (8u60 minimum, 8u121 best)*. This package is called openjdk-8-jdk in the official Ubuntu repositories and its code is 8u121-b13-0ubuntu1. Did you install openjdk-8-jdk too?

To install openjdk-8-jdk open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```